# Поиск элементов WPF по имени

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Есть группа элементов DevExpress.LayoutGroup в котором есть стандартный TextBox и несколько RadioButton.

При вызове события TextBox_TextChanged нужно выставить одну из радио-кнопок в активное положение. Так как я генерирую объекты интерфейса во время выполнения то просто прописать к нужным элементам обработчики не получается. Поэтому я беру родительскую группу LayoutGroup и пытаюсь найти нужную мне кнопку по имени:

```
lgroup.GetElementByName(fname)
```

Но поиск не отрабатывает по непонятным причинам. В других местах поиск пока что работает. Полный код обработчика:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;

        string fname = "RB" + tb.Tag;
        LayoutGroup lgroup = (LayoutGroup)tb.Parent;
        if (lgroup == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lgroup));
        var child = lgroup.GetElementByName(fname);
        if (child == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(child));

        if (child is RadioButton)
        {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) child;
            rb.IsChecked = !tb.Text.IsEmptyOrSingle() ? true : false;
        }
        else if (child is CheckBox)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) child;
            cb.IsChecked = !tb.Text.IsEmptyOrSingle() ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

[image: Дерево элементов]

Поиск элемента здесь всегда дает null. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72857/discussion-between-alias-and-ackbar).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72859/discussion-on-question-by-ackbar---wpf--).